# Utilitarianism and naturalistic fallacy

Tags: ethics, fallacies, utilitarianism, rule-ethics

Does utilitarianism commit the naturalistic fallacy? Can someone tell with respect to act and rule utilitarianism?

Comment: Depends on the Utilitarianism. Hedonism does. Study Moore. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/utilitarianism-history/#IdeUti

Comment: Hi @AdnanZahid, welcome to Phil.SE! How do you see the connection between utilitarianism and naturalistic claims? Please elaborate more, currently your question lacks more clarity for us to provide a proper answer.